# SharePoint 2013 SP1 April 2013 Cumulative Update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I am currently in the process of installing a production server farm, which is a 3-tier server farm (1 DB, 1 application, and 1 web front-end server). The installation completed successfully, but the problem arose when I tried to start the **User Profile Synchronization Service** from the Manage Services on Server on Central Administration (The SharePoint version is SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 (15.0.4569.1506), with SQL Server 2014 SP2).

The service was stuck at starting, and a few minutes later it will stop automatically. From what I've searched on Google, I found that I need to install April 2013 Cumulative Update for SharePoint Server 2013, and I need to install March 2013 Public Update as the requirement.

But when I tried to install the March 2013 PU, or directly install the April 2013 CU, the installer returned **"The expected version of the product was not found on the system"** message.

I've tried to google about the message, and some of them suggests to install the CU / PU from PowerShell, and bypass the version checking (which seems risky enough for me). Any idea about why am I getting those errors? And should I just install the CU / PU, or should I use the latest CU available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First,** you got this error message

> "The expected version of the product was not found on the system"

Because of the cumulative update that you are trying to install ("April 2013") is **lower than** the current build number of your farm that is `"The SharePoint version is SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 (15.0.4569.1506),"`

**Second,** it's known issue that occurs when installing SharePoint 2013 with SQL 2014and to solve this issue you need to install **CU April 2014** (not 2013) or higher.

---

**By the way,** Make sure that

- The Farm account is added to local administrator group only during starting UPS service.
- You are using the Farm Account to start UPSs.

For more details check my detail steps at

- [User Profile Synchronization Service is starting then it stopped!](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)
- [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)